# Type "ParameterEncoding" has no member 'URL' when trying to upload image through Alamofire 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I was using the same code before updating Alamofire to version 4.0 to upload image to server and it was working very good but now I have these errors I'm trying a lot but at each time the new error appears to me  :

First Error:
[image]

Second Error:
[image]

My code:

```
func uploadFile()  {

      let image = UIImage(named: "ios9.jpg")
      let newimage : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage.image!, 32)! as NSData

     let newRandomName = randomStringWithLength(32)
     let fname = (newRandomName as String) + ".jpg"

     let parameters = [
     "pic"           :NetData(data: newimage as Data, mimeType: .ImageJpeg, filename: fname),
     "msg"     :self.detailmsg,
     "customer_key" : self.CUSTOMER_KEY
     ] as [String : Any]



     let urlRequest = self.urlRequestWithComponents("link", parameters: parameters as NSDictionary)


     //First error here
     Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
     .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
     print("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
     }
     .responseJSON { response in
     debugPrint(response)
     }

}


func urlRequestWithComponents(_ urlString:String, parameters:NSDictionary) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

    // create url request to send
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = Alamofire.HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    //let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345"
    let boundaryConstant = "NET-POST-boundary-\(arc4random())-\(arc4random())"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {

        uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

        if value is NetData {
            // add image
            let postData = value as! NetData


            //uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"; filename=\"\(postData.filename)\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

            // append content disposition
            let filenameClause = " filename=\"\(postData.filename)\""
            let contentDispositionString = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\";\(filenameClause)\r\n"
            let contentDispositionData = contentDispositionString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            uploadData.append(contentDispositionData!)


            // append content type
            //uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!) // mark this.
            let contentTypeString = "Content-Type: \(postData.mimeType.getString())\r\n\r\n"
            let contentTypeData = contentTypeString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            uploadData.append(contentTypeData!)
            uploadData.append(postData.data as Data)

        }else{
            uploadData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        }
    }
    uploadData.append("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)



    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
   // return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.encode(mutableURLRequest as! ParameterEncoding).0, uploadData)

    //Second error here
    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}
```

Comment: Insted of doing this you can do it by `multipartFormData`

Comment: @HamzaAnsari how I can do that can you give me example please ?

Comment: @samah how did u fix it? have same issue- Type ParameterEncoding has no member 'url'

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas I was able to get rid of the error by changing 'URL' to lower case 'url'

Answer (score 0):

```
let image = UIImage(named: "ios9.jpg")
let params:[String:Any] = ["msg": self.detailmsg,
                           "customer_key": self.CUSTOMER_KEY]

let urlRequest = try! URLRequest(url: url, method: .post, headers: nil)

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0){
         multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "pic", fileName:"image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
    }
    for (key, value) in self.parameters! {
        let data = "\(value)".data(using: .utf8)
        multipartFormData.append(data!, withName: key)
    }

}, with: urlRequest) { (result) in
       switch result{
       case .success(let request, _, _):
           request.responseJSON { response in
              debugPrint(response)
           }
       case .failure(let error):
             print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
```